# How to know Order is placed from authenticated customer or guest In salesforce commerce cloud?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-chatter, salesforce-commerce-cloud

Hello I am new to salesforce commerce cloud and I am working on controller version of SFCC that is SGJC version. I wanted to know is there is any method or how will we know whether customer who has placed the order has placed as guest or as autheticated customer. I want to write a if else redirection logic. If placed order is from guest redirect to A.isml else redirect to B.isml. Any method from orderMgr class will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

```
var order = OrderMgr.getOrder(orderNo);
var registered = order.getCustomer().isRegistered();
```

From the [docs](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FDWAPI%2Fscriptapi%2Fhtml%2Fapi%2Fclass_dw_customer_Customer.html&anchor=dw_customer_Customer_isRegistered_DetailAnchor)

There is also a difference between Registered and Authenticated customer. An Authenticated customer is a registered customer that is also logged, with an active  authenticated session.

To check if the customer is authenticated you can use isAuthenticated() method instead of isRegistrered()

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code same as below:

```
    var order = OrderMgr.getOrder(orderNo);

    if (!empty(order) && empty(order.getCustomerNo()) {
       // Redirect to A.isml
    }

    if (!empty(order) && !empty(order.getCustomerNo()) {
       // Redirect to B.isml
    }
```

Ref [docs](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FDWAPI%2Fscriptapi%2Fhtml%2Fapi%2Fclass_dw_customer_Customer.html&anchor=dw_customer_Customer_isRegistered_DetailAnchor).